# Getting prompt to allow Adobe Flash Player when navigating to a new SO window

Tags: discussion, bug

Sometimes, today, when I open a new browser window on Stack Overflow I get four prompts in succession whether I want to allow Adobe Flash Player to run

[image]

I get the feeling it happens when an SO window hasn't been used in a while, but I have no exact repro steps.

From comments, adding a screen shot of the ads shown in my SO window, as one might be "rogue":

[image]

IE 11 on Windows 7.

I suspect it's related to other problems the site is experiencing recently...?

Comment: Probably an Ad. Can you screenshot those as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, @rene, I don't follow what you're asking. Where should I belooking for an Ad(vertisement, I assume)? I get this when I click a link within Stack Overflow. For example, in the list of questions visible behind the prompt.

Comment: Yes, I've seen these kind of behavior when an Advertisement went rogue, so to be able to diagnose the SE Dev team is helped I guess if they can see which ads are shown on the page you're on. Below your watched and ignored tags probably ;)  ... my excuse for not being clear about that up-front.

Comment: Understand you now, @rene. I've edited the question with a screen-shot. Thanks for clarifying :-)

Comment: This is suspicious behavior imo. Activating flash only in IE (which is the only actively used browser that doesn't prompt by default, only in protected mode), and only after inactivity sounds malicious. A normal ad would prompt on loading, not after inactivity.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm only seeing it on SO... What do you recommend: closing all browser windows and coming back in? Re-boot windows?

Comment: Step one normally is repro-ing this in safe mode (run `IExplore.exe -extoff`), but you can't since that won't show Flash Player prompts. I don't think there's much you can do outside of reporting it here, most probably it's a malicious ad, and SE should track it down.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth OK. FWIW I closed all the browser windows then came back into SO. Haven't seen it, since; different ads are showing up, so I suspect you and rene are correct. First time I've encountered anything like this - live-and-learn!

Comment: Ads are pretty much the new Flash/Silverlight/Java plugin: something shoved into a site that nulls and voids any capacity to claim your site is secure.

Comment: "Looking for a job" ads are internal SO ads, which are plain text (they don't allow publishers to include their own code). The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please include screenshots of the _actual_ ads you're seeing -- they're pretty bloody obvious. They look like ads anywhere else. Banners, squares in sidebars... those are the ads. What you've screenshotted are bits of the sidebar, not ads. (Sure, a bit of the sidebar that markets another Stack Exchange product, but that's not what we mean when we say 'ad').

Comment: Have you checked active "toolbars and extensions" in Internet Explorer? Perhaps something crept in that for some reason activates on SO?

Comment: @NicHartley These are the only ads I see <shrug>

Comment: @CindyMeister That's... odd, then. It suggests something is loading even with ads disabled. Are you using adblock?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen As mentioned in an earlier comment. Shutting down the browser and re-opening "solved" the issue, in that I didn't see it anymore. FWIW this was the day that a lot was going wrong on the site (bugs) and my first thought was that this was a similar problem. Otherwise I'd have tried that sooner and probably not posted here...

Comment: @NicHartley No, nothing of that nature. But see my most recent previous comment for more details.

Comment: Real answer: stop using IE.